# Java Cplex getting a Heuristics Solution

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to find a good enough solution for a MIP written in Java and solved by CPLEX. Since it takes way too much time, I would be happy enough If I would get a feasible solution. Since CPLEX provides heuristics, is it possible to output a feasible solution calculated by these and later stop the solver?

Comment: In theory there is not much difference between the algorithmic complexity of finding a feasible solution or an optimal feasible one (both NP-hard in general for a MIP). For you the following is probably relevant: [stopping after feasible sol](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400089) + [MIPEmphasis](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9UKU_12.4.0/com.ibm.cplex.zos.help/Parameters/topics/MIPEmphasis.html): telling the solver to focus his attempts to obtain *some* feasible solution. (to be honest: googling would have been faster than asking on SO)

Comment: See also [CPLEX strategies for finding good feasible solutions quickly when solving MIPs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399949).